# Remapping camera's Truck, Yaw and Dolly controls in SceneKit module

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, scenekit

I'd like to programmatically remap the following camera controls in Xcode 9 :

trucking – <kbd>alt</kbd> + LMB

yawing – LMB

dollying – <kbd>alt</kbd> + MMB

`Truck` drags the virtual camera along the X axis, `Yaw` rotates the camera around Y axis and `Dolly` moves the camera forward and backward along local Z axis.

[image]

Is it possible to programmatically reassign (using Swift or Objective-C) mouse hotkeys for truck, yaw and dolly controls in Xcode's module SceneKit (or in XcodeKit module) the same way as it works in Autodesk Maya?

Like that:

trucking – <kbd>alt</kbd> + MMB

yawing – <kbd>alt</kbd> + LMB

dollying – <kbd>alt</kbd> + RMB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough investigation I could say there's no way (at the moment) to remap camera controls programmatically or manually in Xcode 9/10.

Looking forward to seeing Xcode 11 supported features.